# Utilizador adicionar data para List MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sou novo em ASP.NET MVC 4 e C# e preciso de ajuda. Criei uma classe Enrollment (disciplina)

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Como podem ver tem uma lista de componentes

```
public class Component
{
    public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Enrollment Enrollment { get; set; }
}
```

Criei controllers e views usando EF. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que um utilizador possa seleccionar uma disciplina que já exista e adicione componentes a ela. Basicamente o que está feito é que um utilizador vai ao index das disciplinas e vê todas as disciplinas, essas disciplinas teem um link que vai para a pagina de details onde aparece os componentes, e queria que ai fosse possivel criar apenas os componentes para essa disciplina. Se souberem outra maneira de fazer também serve. Obrigado desde já.

View Index dos enrollments (disciplinas):

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.EnrollmentId })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EnrollmentId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EnrollmentId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

View Details dos Componentes:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="display-field">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Components)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Então, sobre o Id da disciplina, minha resposta explica. Você precisa chamar a `Action` usando um link como `http://exemplo:12345/Components/CreateByEnrollmentId/{idDaDisciplina}`.

Answer (score 2):

Tem algumas formas de fazer. A mais didática seria criar uma *Action* em `ComponentsController` para criar um componente da disciplina usando o Id da Disciplina. Por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult CreateByEnrollmentId(int id) 
{
    var enrollment = context.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EnrollmentId == id);
    if (enrollment == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    // Aqui sabemos que a disciplina já existe, então posso montar um
    // objeto com EnrollmentId já definido.

    var component = new Component 
    {
        EnrollmentId = enrollment.EnrollmentId
    }

    return View("Create", component);
}
```

Com isso, a tela de Create já vem com `EnrollmentId` preenchido e você pode transformar a `dropdown` de disciplinas em um `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnrollmentId)`.

Outra forma é usando o componente [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) nas telas de criação e edição das disciplinas. [Já há muitas respostas sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem), então peço para que veja as respostas para ver se é isso mesmo que procura.

Comment: Irei testar e também ver sobre BeginCollectionItem e direi algo depois, obrigado. Só uma duvida, dentro da view Details dos Enrollments crio um link directamente para a view create dos Components? Como faço para que o id da disciplina escolhida depois seja utilizado na criação do componente?