# Passagem de id para novo controller MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Continuando o tópico anterior ([Utilizador adicionar data para List MVC 4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125065/utilizador-adicionar-data-para-list-mvc-4)) tenho uma nova dúvida. Podem ver nesse tópico a questão inicial e a resposta que me foi dada, mas precisava de lhe responder mas não me é permitido. Seguindo a resposta do user, criei este código:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.EnrollmentId = new SelectList(db.Enrollments, "EnrollmentId", "Name");
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Component component)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Components.Add(component);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.EnrollmentId = new SelectList(db.Enrollments, "EnrollmentId", "Name", componente.EnrollmentId);
    return View(component);
}

public ActionResult CreateByEnrollmentId(int id) 
{
    var enrollment = db.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EnrollmentId == id);
    if (enrollment == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var component = new Component
    {
        EnrollmentId = enrollment.EnrollmentId
    };

    return View("Create", component);
}
```

No entanto quando crio um component realmente passa o id (diz components/create/1 por ex.) mas continua a dar o erro ""O campo EnrollmentId é necessário." Alguém me consegue ajudar? Obrigado

**Edit: View Create**

```
 @model PFC.Models.Component

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Component</legend>


        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnrollmentId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div> 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Na linha `db.Components.Add(component);`, quais valores tem no objeto `component`?

Comment: Poste também a sua View Create.

Comment: Editei com a view create.
Os valores que tem no objecto component é o EnrollmentId e o Name

Comment: Acho que você está usando o site aqui errado. Você poderia ter editado sua pergunta anterior ou ter aberto uma nova pergunta com o usuário anterior. De qualquer forma, vou tentar responder.

Answer (score 2):

Como eu havia dito na pergunta anterior, você precisa preencher o `EnrollmentId` como *hidden* se ele tiver valor, ou trazer a *dropdown* preenchida em caso contrário. Uma sugestão de código seria o seguinte:

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Component</legend>

        @if (Model != null && Model.EnrollmentId != null && Model.EnrollmentId != 0)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnrollmentId)
        } 
        else 
        {
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EnrollmentId, (SelectList)ViewBag.EnrollmentId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentId)
            </div>
        }

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div> 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Faça um *debug* na *Action* com `[HttpPost]` para verificar se os valores estão sendo preenchidos corretamente.

Comment: Ele não está a passar o EnrollmentId. Ha de passar algum valor tanto que o link fica /Component/Create/1, mas não está a passar esse id. O código acima deu erro no if

Comment: Está errado, como eu disse na outra resposta. O link deve ser `/Component/CreateByEnrollmentId/1`. Atualizei a resposta.